# Cannot GET /index.js error deploying reactjs app in Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I'm working on this reactJS simple app that I created, it works and run locally but when I try to deploy it in Heroku, it throws an error. I'm new to this framework.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sample react project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "matt morales",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
    "xhr": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0"
  }
}
```

Procfile

```
web: node server.js

webpack.config
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path:'/',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Here's the file structure:

[image: i]

Error:

```
2017-03-10T02:38:33.489173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-10T02:38:35.909403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2017-03-10T02:38:39.567325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-10T02:38:52.406683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=reactappby.herokuapp.com request_id=ba15080a-49f0-4dd1-ba66-98a71e3b4f41 fwd="121.96.240.43" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=610 protocol=https
```

Comment: Please post the error you get from Heroku when you attempt to deploy.

Comment: added the error log.the problem I guess is with react-router

Comment: The log you provided does not show the error- it just shows the sequence of starting up the application and receiving a 200 status (ok status) back. Can you post where you see the error message?